# H2にてschema定義のsqlを読み込ませる方法

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit

複数のDBに接続するアプリーションの開発中です。
UTでJunit4を使っており、H２でMysqlのDBを立てています。
Mysqlの方にテーブル定義のsqlを読み込ませたいのですが、schema.sqlと言うファイルをsrc/test/resources配下に置いて、application.ymlで読み込ませるように記述してもテーブルの作成がされておらずテストが途中で失敗します。

下記の書き方で間違いがあるんでしょうか？

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    mysql:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
      password: hoge
      username: hgoe
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    oracle:
      url: hoge
      username: hoge
      password: hoge
      driver-class-name: hoge
  sql:
    init:
      schema-locations: classpath*:schema.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、H2への接続なのでドライバもH2用のもの `org.h2.Driver` を用いる必要があります:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    mysql:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
      password: hoge
      username: hgoe
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

その上で、複数のデータソースが存在する状態で `schema.sql` が自動で適用されるのは `@Primary` として定義されているものだけです。

- [17.8.2. Configure Two DataSources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources)

  > `firstDataSourceProperties` has to be flagged as `@Primary` so that the database initializer feature uses your copy (if you use the initializer).

こちらで詳しく解説されています:

- [Spring Boot: 複数DB利用時に初期化が期待通りに行われない問題と解決法 - Rhythm & Biology](https://mythosil.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/07/28/181613)

対応としては、上記リンク先にもありますが、自前で `DataSourceInitializer` bean を定義すれば良いです。
今回はテストコード向けなので、 `src/test/java` 配下のクラスとして次のような実装を行うことになるでしょう:

```java
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

@Configuration
public class MyTestConfig {

    // mysqlDataSource は、実際にはあなたが定義したH2データソースbean名
    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer mysqlDataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") final DataSource datasource) {
        final ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
        // resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data.sql"));

        final DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

}
```